# Unable to get the listing of files / objects in S3 bucket ; iOS - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to get the list of objects in an S3 bucket. Below is the code but it doesn't seems to be working , neither is it throwing an error. However, the S3 object seemed to be (0x000000000) uninitialised.
I am not sure what's the mistake because the configuration is working for uploading a file to the bucket.

```js
class Configuration {
    let accessKey = Constants.AWS_KEY
    let secretKey = Constants.AWS_SECRET
    let bucket = Constants.AWS_BUCKET
    
    static let instance = Configuration()
    
    private init() {
        let credentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: accessKey, secretKey: secretKey)
        let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
        AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
        AWSS3.register(with: configuration!, forKey: "defaultKey")
    }
}
```

```js
class S3Browser {
    
    static let configuration = Configuration.instance
    static func getList(path:String) {
        

        let s3 = AWSS3.s3(forKey: "defaultkey")
       
        let listRequest: AWSS3ListObjectsRequest = AWSS3ListObjectsRequest()
        //listRequest.prefix = path
        listRequest.bucket = Constants.AWS_BUCKET
       
        s3.listObjects(listRequest).continueWith { (task) -> AnyObject? in

           for object in (task.result?.contents)! {
               
               print("Object key = \(object.key!)")
           }
           
           return nil
        }
    }
}
```

All the keys and secrets are working for upload.
Kindly share some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your permissions on AWS. Just because you have permission to upload doesn't mean you have permission to list the files in the S3 bucket.

How do you know the upload is working? Have you browsed in a web browser, the bucket at the AWS S3 site?

Comment: I know upload works because the bucket is public to read and I can check file from URL . Also in android SDK its working so I know this works , problem is on iOS sdk